# Does Shield of Faith stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Could shield of faith cast by multiple casters stack on one creature?

Comment: I've removed the [rules-as-written] tag from this question. This is a fairly ordinary rules inquiry, which doesn't appear to leverage the constraints we have the rules as written tag for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No

Spells don't stack with themselves.

**Combining Magical Effects:**

> The effects of different spells add together while the durations of those spells overlap. **The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don't combine, however.** Instead, the most potent effect — such as the highest bonus — from those castings applies while their durations overlap. (PHB 205)

Answer (score 4):

### Short answer:

No.

### Long Answer:

As long as an effect is active on the player, you can't stack it, casting it again would just extend the duration.

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer: Nooooooooooooooo.

Comment: Skallagrim memes are the best.